# Removing all layers from group using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, layers, group-layer

I want to remove all layers from a distinct group.

```py
root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
the_group = root.findGroup("my_group")

parentGroup = the_group.parent()
```

I think I have to loop the elements of the group and remove them

```py
for i in parentGroup.children():
...
```

And then calling the `removeMapLayer()` method within the loop.

But I can't put these things together.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`dump()` method of QgsLayerTreeLayer should be only used for debug purpose. You can do it much nicer this way:

```
root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
group = root.findGroup(groupName)

if group is not None:
    for child in group.children():
        if isinstance(child, QgsLayerTreeLayer):
            QgsProject.instance().removeMapLayer(child.layerId())
```

The code above will remove all layers that are immediately inside the group. If the group has subgroups inside and they also have layers, they won't be removed.

---

If you want to remove the whole group instead (with layers and groups inside), just call:

```
root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
group = root.findGroup(groupName)
if group is not None:
    root.removeChildNode(group)
```

Answer (score 7):

I have this function to remove a group and all his layers. I think is nearly what you want.

```
def removeGroup(name):
    root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
    group = root.findGroup(name)
    if not group is None:
        for child in group.children():
            dump = child.dump()
            id = dump.split("=")[-1].strip()
            QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().removeMapLayer(id)
        root.removeChildNode(group)
```

You could use it like this:

```
removeGroup("groupname")
```

If you dont want to remove the group, just his child layers, then remove this line:

```
root.removeChildNode(group)
```

Answer (score 4):

Update for **QGIS 3**.

Based in @cag answer only need change this line :

```
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().removeMapLayer(id)
```

to

```
QgsProject.instance().removeMapLayer(id)
```

And work like a charm