# removeGroup() in QGIS 3

Tags: pyqgis, legend

I am updating a plugin from QGIS 2 to 3.  I need to iterate through the groups (the names are dynamic) and remove them with their respective child layers.  I need to get a list of groups and then iterate through the groups and delete them.  The original code is as follows:

```
legend = self.iface.legendInterface()
group_names = legend.groups()
rev = self.groups[:]
rev.reverse()
...
    for i, group in enumerate(rev):
        legend.removeGroup(group)
```

I replaced `self.iface.legendInterface()` with `QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()` but `group_names = legend.groups()` fails with the message *'QgsLayerTree' object has no attribute 'groups'*

What is the proper container of the groups and how do I access the collection; and, once found, how do I delete those groups?  A search for information on how to remove groups from a layer tree in QGIS 3 has proven fruitless.

Comment: This QA https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/198296/how-to-remove-all-layers-from-a-group/198298 might get you going in the right direction.

Comment: Unfortunately, the referenced link is of little help. For one, I cannot perform a findGroup() by group name because I do not know the name(s).  There may be several, so I will need to iterate through them by index, not by name.  Additionally, I need to delete the group, not just the layers in it.

Answer (score 5):

You could delete groups by removing their nodes from the [QgsProject::layerTreeRoot()](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsProject.html#a87b79d1ee448a7638b7b9f405a3837d7).

The following example iterates through the groups and removes a group and all of its layers if the name matches:

```
root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()

for group in [child for child in root.children() if child.nodeType() == 0]:
    if group.name() == 'group1':
        root.removeChildNode(group)
```

Comment: Since group the names may be dynamically generated, I will never know all the names, but I can simply remove the `if` and iterate through them all and delete them all (which is the aim of the algorithm). Upvoted!

Comment: @CNIDog - Glad it helped :)