# Removing a group from layers panel using PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, group-layer, remove

How can I remove a group that I created previously using :

```
groupName="machin"

root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()

group = root.addGroup(groupName)
```

Comment: Similar question was posted recently: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/319515/removegroup-in-qgis-3

Comment: ok, thanx for help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this

```
root.removeChildNode(group)
```